# Why do I have to declare DataContext when binding to relative source

Tags: mvvm, datacontext

When I bind I normally just enter the name of the property which exists in the DataContext

EG

```
Text = {Binding MyProp}"
```

When I use relative source, I have to use DataContext

```
Text = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.MyProp }" />
```

I must be missing some basic understanding as I don't see why I need to include the word DataContext in the path: `Path=DataContext.MyProp`, I had assumed it has implicit. If I remove DataContext from the string, then it won't bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RelativeSource will change the target to, in this instance, UserControl. This way you can bind to elements on the UserControl, such as its Width/Height/etc. In these cases having an implicit DataContext would be counter-productive.

Comment: This means if I were to bind to Width, I would not use DataContext.Width, but just Width?

Comment: That is correct. Basically, by default, a binding target starts at DataContext (which can be inherited from other controls - doesn't need to be set independently). However when you change the target, i.e. point it at your user control, then that is the new target.